# FIndWindow() not working after BM_CLICK

Tags: button, vb6, controls, windows-api-code-pack

I am using `SendMessage()` to send a `BM_CLICK` to a button that opens a popup window and then trying to use `FindWindow()` to find the ID for this window. When I manually click the button or press enter once selecting the button I can find the window ID fine but when I send the button a `BM_CLICK` message I am unable to find the window. I've set a timer in case I was looking for the window too early but no luck. Is there any difference between an actual click and using `BM_CLICK` that would cause this problem? Here is my code:

```
Call SendMessage(hist_ID, BM_CLICK, 0, 0)
Sleep 500

hist_window_id = FindWindow("ThunderRT6FormDC", "Select History Data")

timeout = 0
Do While hist_window_id = 0
    If timeout < 20 Then
        Sleep 50
        hist_window_id = FindWindow("ThunderRT6FormDC", "Select History Data")
        timeout = timeout + 1
    Else
        MsgBox "System Timeout"
        Exit Function
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: Yes I only get it when using BM_CLICK

Comment: PostMessage() worked! Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

`SendMessage()` waits for the message to be handled before continuing. If the button click event handler is displaying a modal window, it may be blocking your VB program until the window is dismissed. Use `PostMessage()` instead.